# Convert ARGB data(.tiff image) to 2D texture using D3D11

Tags: directx, argb

I have a sample ARGB image (.tiff file).

I want to pass it as a 2D texture. I am not sure how to do that or is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can utilize [WIC texture loader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader) which is a part of official [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).